# Formatting page titles: Organization first or page, and which delimiter

Tags: website-design, html, title

Usually there is a format for page titles:

```
{{page_name}} | {{organization_name}}
```

Sometimes the delimiter is a bar, a hyphen, a slash...  Sometimes the organization comes first.

I would think that the organization second makes sense, since most websites will have a unique favicon that will act as the organizational logo.  I would also guess that hyphens would work as a delimiter, since it works well in urls to make them more SEO friendly.

Wondering if there are any other thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2):

Browser title bars, tabs, search engine results etc. can only display a limited number of characters in the title. Having the organization name at the front takes up valuable space and doesn't provide much more useful information to the user.

An instance when you may want the organization name in front would be if branding is very important:

> If a brand is well-known enough to make a difference in click-through
>   rates in search results, the brand name should be first. If the brand
>   is less known or relevant than the keyword, the keyword should be
>   first. (http://moz.com/learn/seo/title-tag)

Answer (score 1):

You should put the most usable portion first, which is usually the page name.

Imagine if you had a series of tabs or bookmarks that all looked like this:

```
User Experience Stack Exchange | Web...
User Experience Stack Exchange | Usa...
User Experience Stack Exchange | Int...
```

In addition to SEO, page titles are very useful to your users when they are operating in a multi-tabbed environment.  As such, you need to ensure that the portion of the title that they are most likely to see is the most useful portion.